# find certain files and copy their content into new file in bash

Tags: bash, find, copy, subdirectory

I want to find all the files with the same name (File.txt) in my current directory (./parent) and subdirectories (./parent/subdirectory{1..100}) and copy their content to a new file (line by line) in the parent directory.
any ideas?

Comment: Use the `find` command to find all the files. Why do you need to copy line by line instead of just using the `cp` command to copy the entire file at once?

Comment: I want to make a larger file which contains the content of all my "File.txt" files.

Comment: Then use `cat file1 file2 file3 ... > output.txt`

Comment: yes cat works, but I'd like to find my files first. how would you mix find (or grep) with cat? any faster solution?

Comment: `cat **/File.txt > output.txt` (might need a `shopt -s globstar` first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you ?

```bash
find . -name File.txt -exec cat {} + > full.txt
```

Comment: The shell doesn't care, but it's confusing to put `\;` after the redirection. We usually put redirection at the end of a command, not between arguments.

Comment: Why `-iname` instead of `-name`?

Comment: Yes -name does the job, sorry, I'm used to -iname which is case insensitive. About the `\;`, I was just considering the redirection to be part of the command. But I get the argument

Comment: But the redirection isn't part of the `-exec` command argument -- if it were you would be overwriting the output file for each file it finds. That's what makes your original syntax misleading.

Comment: `-exec cat {} +` would be more efficient.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I edited my answer with your recommandations.